# How to use Moose to add convenience functions for array attributes?

Tags: perl, moose

This is a basic question, I fear. Take a look at the following code. I'd like to know whether there is a way to declare the `slices` attribute in such a way as to avoid the boilerplate of `get_slices` and `add_slice`.

```
package Gurke;
use Moose;

has slices => is => 'rw', isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]', default => sub { [] };

sub get_slices { return @{ $_[0]->slices } }

sub add_slice {
    my( $self, $slice ) = @_;
    push @{ $self->slices }, $slice;
    return;
}

no Moose;
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

package main; # now a small test for the above package
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;
my $gu = Gurke->new;
$gu->add_slice( 'eins' );
$gu->add_slice( 'zwei' );
$gu->add_slice( 'drei' );
my @sl = $gu->get_slices;
is shift @sl, 'eins';
is shift @sl, 'zwei';
is shift @sl, 'drei';
done_testing;
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm trying to imagine what the cucumber looks like that you can put slices of something in... :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm a Moose beginner, but I think you need this:

```
has slices =>
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'ArrayRef[Str]',
    default => sub { [] },
    traits  => ['Array'],
    handles => {
        add_slice  => 'push',
        get_slices => 'elements',
    },
;
```

Comment: Thanks, dear fellow Moose beginner. This works, and is exactly what I wanted. I had tried both `traits` and `handled` but failed to see that they're supposed to be combined. - And if you happen to know how to make Moose die on being passed an undeclared attribute I'd be thankful too. :-) [How to make the Moose constructor die on being passed an undeclared attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818948)